# Split a column using the union join in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, union

I've got a table with manufacturer and orderdate on it, i need to find the amount of orders per manufacturer for 2011 and 2012. I can get the information but I need three columns, Make, orders for 2011 and orders for 2012. I have been told i can do this using a union join but i can't figure it out for the life of me. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please state which database product you use.

Comment: can you be more clear by providing rdbms using,table structure with sample data and also expected result ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide many details but it sounds like you want to *pivot* the data from rows into columns.  If so, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the data into columns:

```
select manufacturer,
  sum(case when datepart(year, orderdate) = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) Orders_2011,
  sum(case when datepart(year, orderdate) = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) Orders_2012
from yourtable
group by manufacturer
```

This will create the data in the following format:

```
Manufacturer | Orders_2011 | Orders_2012
Comp1        | 100         | 78
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I was originally using Select Make, Count(make)'Orders', 
FROM Table
Where dateordered In ('2012', '2011')
Group by Make;

And I was told to do the union join in here.